# Bash grep doesn't return the first regex match

Tags: regex, shell, grep

So I have shell script like this:

```
echo "stackoverflow.com:1111/?a=b&c=d" | grep -o "^.*[/:\n]"
```

and it returns

```
stackoverflow.com:1111/
```

Shouldn't it return the first prefix before one of the symbols '/', ':' or '\n'?
How do I make it return

```
stackoverflow.com:
```

using regexp?

Comment: Try it like this `echo "stackoverflow.com:1111/?a=b&c=d" | grep -o "^[^/:\n]*"`

Comment: It works @Thefourthbird, at least in Ubuntu 18.04

Comment: Regex is greedy!

Comment: The `\n` is superfluous; `grep` never matches past a newline anyway.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can exclude the characters `/` `:` or `\n` using a negated character class `^[^/:\n]*`

Using `\n` with `-P` for a Perl compatible regex:

```
echo "stackoverflow.com:1111/?a=b&c=d" | grep -oP "^[^/:\n]*"
```

Or exluding whitespaces from the string without `-P`

```
echo "stackoverflow.com:1111/?a=b&c=d" | grep -o "^[^/:[:space:]]*"
```

[Bash demo](https://tio.run/##S0oszvj/PzU5I19BqbgkMTk7vyy1KC0nv1wvOT/XyhAI9O0TbZPUkm1TlBRqFNKLUgsUdPMDFJTiouP0rWLyYrWU/v8HAA)

---

If you want to match the `:` at the end as well, you can match it `^[^/:\n]*:`

[Bash demo](https://tio.run/##S0oszvj/PzU5I19BqbgkMTk7vyy1KC0nv1wvOT/XyhAI9O0TbZPUkm1TlBRqFNKLUgsUdPMDFJTiouP0rWLyYrWslP7/BwA)

Answer (score 0):

Use `-P` (Perl regexes), remove the extra `\n` (not needed for `grep`, since it is line-based by default), and change the greedy modifier `*` to non-greedy modifier `*?`:

```
echo "stackoverflow.com:1111/?a=b&c=d" | grep -oP "^.*?[/:]"
```

Output:

```
stackoverflow.com:
```